# How to extract link to Package Sources from Arch User Repository (AUR) website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to extract this line:

```
<a href="https://github.com/J-Lentz/iwgtk/archive/v0.8.tar.gz">iwgtk-0.8.tar.gz</a>
```

from a webpage.

```
<div>
    <ul id="pkgsrcslist">
        <li>
            <a href="https://github.com/J-Lentz/iwgtk/archive/v0.8.tar.gz">iwgtk-0.8.tar.gz</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Specifically, I want this part: **iwgtk-0.8.tar.gz**

I've written this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url="https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/iwgtk"
#url=sys.argv[1]

page = requests.get(url)
if page.status_code ==200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    urls = []
# loop over the [li] tags
    for tag in soup.find_all('li'):
        atag = tag.find('a')
        try:
            if 'href' in atag.attrs:
                url = atag.get('href').contents[0]
                urls.append(url)
        except:
            pass

# print all the urls stored in the urls list
for url in urls:
    print(url)
```

and I assume it is this line

```
url = atag.get('href').contents[0]
```

that fails. I've tried

```
url = atag.get('a').contents[0]
```

but that failed too.

Comment: you said that want this part: iwgtk-0.8.tar.gz but tried to extract `href`, that's not the same. So you need `href`s or link text ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to select your elements more specific:

```
soup.find('ul',{'id':'pkgsrcslist'}).find_all('a')
```

or more comfortable via [`css selector`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)

```
soup.select('#pkgsrcslist a')
```

and use `get('href')` to get the url or `text` / `get_text()` to get its text or use both and store as key value in `dict`:

```
...
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
pkgs = {}

for tag in soup.select('#pkgsrcslist a'):
    print('url: ' +tag.get('href'))
    print('text: ' + tag.text)
    ### update your a dict of package versions and links
    pkgs.update({
        tag.text:tag.get('href')
    })
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url="https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/iwgtk"

page = requests.get(url)
if page.status_code ==200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    pkgs = {}
    for tag in soup.select('#pkgsrcslist a'):
        pkgs.update({
            tag.text:tag.get('href')
        })

print(pkgs)
```

##### Output

```
{'iwgtk-0.8.tar.gz': 'https://github.com/J-Lentz/iwgtk/archive/v0.8.tar.gz'}
```

Comment: The important here is the [CSS-selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) `#pkgsrcslist a` which selects all links (tag `a`) inside the element with id `pkgsrcslist`. It can be used with the `select` method instead of `find` or `find_all`.

Comment: It's very useful that I can extract what I need using soup.select. So all I should do, in fact, is simply print tag,text to get the tarfile name.

Answer (score 0):

You can also query the AUR repository using the official [Aurweb RPC interface](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Aurweb_RPC_interface) using the type `search` with a search-term as `arg`:

https://aur.archlinux.org/rpc/?v=5&type=search&arg=iwgtk

It returns JSON by default:

```json
{
  "resultcount": 1,
  "results": [
    {
      "Description": "Lightweight wireless network management GUI (front-end for iwd)",
      "FirstSubmitted": 1597306328,
      "ID": 1124939,
      "LastModified": 1660234078,
      "Maintainer": "J-Lentz",
      "Name": "iwgtk",
      "NumVotes": 19,
      "OutOfDate": null,
      "PackageBase": "iwgtk",
      "PackageBaseID": 156689,
      "Popularity": 1.748972,
      "URL": "https://github.com/J-Lentz/iwgtk",
      "URLPath": "/cgit/aur.git/snapshot/iwgtk.tar.gz",
      "Version": "0.8-2"
    }
  ],
  "type": "search",
  "version": 5
}
```

Your wanted information can be found at JSON-path `.results[].URLPath`.

See also:

- ArchWiki: [Arch package guidelines - section 7 **Package sources**](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Arch_package_guidelines#Package_sources)